# temporary signed url always expired laravel

Tags: laravel, docker

After porting a Laravel 5.7 application to Docker, temporary signed URLs always have expired status

Function looks like

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('2FA Reset Confirmation')
            ->view('emails.confirmReset2fa',[
                'link' => URL::temporarySignedRoute(
                    '2fa.reset.confirm', now()->addMinutes(30), ['user' => $this->resetUser->id]
                )
            ]);
```

Inside the container nginx, php-fpm and the application itself are configured. The container is located behind traefik

Comment: An example of the generated html that links to the signed url? i would be concerned that there is added a click identifier or similar.

Comment: @mrhn thanks for you interest! The problem was solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved my issue.
The problem was with loadbalancer and next code, that I added to force HTTPS.

```
if (env('APP_ENV') == 'prod' or env('APP_ENV') == 'dev') {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

I need to add `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies = '*';

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies